# Google Cloud appengine deployment: No app found

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I have inherited a php codebase that uses google appengine, so I have a fully built app locally that I am trying to deploy.  But when I run:

```
gcloud app deploy --project project-name --verbosity=debug
```

I get the error below. I don't understand the staging command error because in the app.yaml I specify `runtime: php55`.  I don't know what the API endpoint error means, and I also don't understand why no app was found.  Any help on any of these errors would be much appreciated.

> DEBUG: Running [gcloud.app.deploy] with arguments: [--project:
>   "project-name", --verbosity: "debug"] DEBUG: No staging command found
>   for runtime [php55] and environment [STANDARD]. DEBUG: API endpoint:
>   [https://appengine.googleapis.com/], API version: [v1] DEBUG: No app
>   found: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/myname/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py",
>   line 679, in _PossiblyCreateApp
>       return api_client.GetApplication()   File "/Users/myname/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/appengine_api_client.py",
>   line 66, in GetApplication
>       return self.client.apps.Get(request)   File "/Users/myname/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/apis/appengine/v1/appengine_v1_client.py",
>   line 1124, in Get
>       config, request, global_params=global_params)   File "/Users/myname/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py",
>   line 722, in _RunMethod
>       return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)   File
>   "/Users/myname/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py",
>   line 728, in ProcessHttpResponse
>       self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request))   File
>   "/Users/myname/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/py/base_api.py",
>   line 599, in __ProcessHttpResponse
>       http_response, method_config=method_config, request=request) HttpNotFoundError: HttpError accessing
>   https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/project-name?alt=json:
>   response: <{'status': '404', 'content-length': '136',
>   'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
>   'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer',
>   'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control':
>   'private', 'date': 'Tue, 24 Sep 2019 22:49:44 GMT', 'x-frame-options':
>   'SAMEORIGIN', 'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"',
>   'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
>   "error": {
>       "code": 404,
>       "message": "Could not find Application \"project-name\".",
>       "status": "NOT_FOUND"   } }

Comment: Can you please add a minimum reproducable code sample to reproduce the issue (exclude any sensitive info)? Also, I suppose that you put your actual project name in the gcloud command but you redacted it when you posted the question?

Comment: I did redact the project name in my post.  In the future I'll try to make that more obvious.  As for minimum reproducible code, I've since figured out the problem and it had to do entirely with trying to deploy an empty project.

Comment: Glad to hear that the issue is resolved. I hope you enjoy experimenting with the App Engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for `--project` must correspond to a Google Cloud Platform project ID.

It's unclear whether you replaced your actual project ID (NB Project IDs and Project names are distinct properties, see [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects)) with `project-name` when you pasted your question.

One way to verify that the project exists would be to:

```sh
gcloud projects describe [[PROJECT]]
```

Assuming the project exists, a second consideration is that (since you're not specifying [`deployables`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy)), the command assumes the working directory contains an `app.yaml` (App Engine app configuration) file.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem ended up being that the project which I was trying to access DID exist, but was empty, so there was no app to run.  In my post I had mistakenly assumed that deploying the app happened locally, hence my confusion about it not finding the app.yaml